# Nova Compute High availability

Tags: openstack

I had deployed 3 virtual controller with Fencing for HA.I tried Nova compute HA using Ceph backend.But i cant able to fency the VM to another compute node when the Primary node shutdown.

Comment: Ceph only provides high availability for the RBD images (if your pools are configured properly), not HA for compute nodes. There was a project called [Masakari](https://docs.openstack.org/masakari/latest/) but it's not properly maintained anymore, I believe. There is currently no other project I'm aware of. If your compute node fails so it doesn't respond to (live) migration actions you'll need to edit the nova.instances database, change the `host` and `node` entries for your vm to a different compute node, then reboot hard that instance so it will be restarted on a different compute node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance HA automates the evacuation of an instance whenever its host Compute node fails. The evacuation process triggered by Instance HA is similar to what users can do manually, as described in Evacuate Instances. Instance HA works on shared storage and local storage environments, which means that evacuated instances will maintain the same network configuration (static ip, floating ip, and so on) and characteristics inside the new host, even if they are spawned from scratch.

Instance HA is managed by three resource agents:

fence_compute: Marks a Compute node for evacuation when the node becomes unavailable

NovaEvacuate: Evacuates instances from failed nodes, and runs on one of the Controller nodes

nova-compute-wait: Restarts Compute services on an instance once it is fully evacuated to a functional Compute host.

For more information you can go through this [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_openstack_platform/10/html-single/high_availability_for_compute_instances/index)